# R (data.table) Find calendar month with largest share of days in interval

Tags: r, loops, date, data.table

I have a large dataset with information on hospitalizations, date of admission and date of discharge.

I would like to find, for each hospitalization, the calendar month that contains the largest share of the hospitalization spell. In case the days between admission and discharge are equally distributed across months, I would like to associate it with the month of admission.

Below is a simple example:

```
hosp_dates <- data.table(id = c(1:5), 
                         dt_admission = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-10", "2002-01-16", "2005-01-17", "2010-01-20")),
                         dt_discharge =  as.Date(c("2000-01-20", "2000-02-02", "2002-02-16", "2005-02-16", "2010-03-31")))

hosp_dates %>%
  mutate(month = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), 
         year = c(2000, 2000, 2002, 2005, 2010))
```

Output

```
   id dt_admission dt_discharge month year
1:  1   2000-01-01   2000-01-20     1 2000
2:  2   2000-01-10   2000-02-02     1 2000
3:  3   2002-01-16   2002-02-16     1 2002
4:  4   2005-01-17   2005-02-16     2 2005
5:  5   2010-01-20   2010-03-31     3 2010
```

Comment: Are the *hospitalization spell* always shorter than one year?

Comment: Unfortunately no, @sindri_baldur

Comment: So maybe the updated solution is more appropriate

Comment: @sindri_baldur I am getting the following error message when running this code in my real data `Error in seq.Date(dt_admission, dt_discharge, 1L) : 'from' must be of length 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

À la brute-force (assuming distinct ids):

```
library(collapse)
hosp_dates[, 
           c('m', 'y') := {
             sd = seq.Date(dt_admission, dt_discharge, 1L)
             .(fmode(month(sd)), fmode(year(sd)))
           }, 
           by = id]

#       id dt_admission dt_discharge     m     y
#    <int>       <Date>       <Date> <int> <int>
# 1:     1   2000-01-01   2000-01-20     1  2000
# 2:     2   2000-01-10   2000-02-02     1  2000
# 3:     3   2002-01-16   2002-02-16     1  2002
# 4:     4   2005-01-17   2005-02-16     2  2005
# 5:     5   2010-01-20   2010-03-31     3  2010
```

If you have admissions lasting more than 11 months you'll get results different from what you are expecting and you might prefer something such as:

```
hosp_dates[, 
           ym := format(seq.Date(dt_admission, dt_discharge, 1L), "%Y-%m") |>
             fmode(), 
           by = id]

#       id dt_admission dt_discharge      ym
#    <int>       <Date>       <Date>  <char>
# 1:     1   2000-01-01   2000-01-20 2000-01
# 2:     2   2000-01-10   2000-02-02 2000-01
# 3:     3   2002-01-16   2002-02-16 2002-01
# 4:     4   2005-01-17   2005-02-16 2005-02
# 5:     5   2010-01-20   2010-03-31 2010-03
```